# Laravel cache:config crashes all the application

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a Laravel application and I run into something very strange I can't understand. I was working with some route and I did clear routes, cache and also run the command config:cache and everything was down throwing this kind of exception everywhere also running all the other commands like composer dump-autoload but the error doesn't get fixed. Here is the exception:

> 'Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 767
>
> ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 767

Call Stack:

```
0.4138     377688   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\artisan:0
0.4774    2866472   2. App\Console\Kernel->handle() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\artisan:37
0.4820    2912464   3. App\Console\Kernel->reportException() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:132
0.4838    2977184   4. App\Exceptions\Handler->report() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:353
0.4838    2977184   5. App\Exceptions\Handler->report() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\app\Exceptions\Handler.php:39
0.4870    3122168   6. Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php:113
0.4870    3122168   7. Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php:519
0.4870    3122168   8. Illuminate\Log\LogManager->getDefaultDriver() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php:103
0.4870    3122168   9. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->offsetGet() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php:436
0.4870    3122168  10. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1210
0.4870    3122168  11. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:734
0.4870    3122168  12. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:601
0.4871    3122168  13. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->build() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:646
0.4871    3122288  14. ReflectionClass->__construct() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\mystyle\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:767'
```

Fortunately, I have a previous commit in an online repository and I deleted everything and pulled it and tried again cache:config and the error came again.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Create new branch from crashy code, pull correct code and compare it. Also if there are some class changes you would like to do `composer dump-autoload` to refresh autoload's references.

Comment: amazing idea , thank you , once i will try i will respond again to the comment

Comment: Just go ahead. No other way to know what has been changed.